# CSS selector for dynamically generated div's

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select each dynamically generated div by class?

```
<div class="thumbs-1 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="thumbs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="thumbs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="thumbs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
etc
```

My static simplified css looks like

```
.thumbs-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.thumbs-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.thumbs-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

}
.thumbs-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

How can I make my .css file dynamic??

Comment: Why not use .thumbs as class name instead of thumbs-1 etc, if the CSS content is the same in each case?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a form of regex

```
div[class^='thumbs-'] {
    color: black;  
}
```

Means, select class with name starting from `thumbs-`

Comment: How do i combine the thumbs- with img so i can target .thumbs-1 img {
div[class^='thumbs-'] img ??

Comment: `div[class^='thumbs-'] img{
    width:20px;
}` that way you can select img elements inside divs with classes starting from `thumbs-`

Answer (score 2):

Use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[class^="thumbs"]{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

`[attr^=value]`

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".

Comment: looks promising how can target .thumbs-1 img {

Comment: `[class^="thumbs"] img{`

Answer (score 2):

You want the following CSS selector

```
div[class^="thumbs-"], div[class*=" thumbs-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: tx guys using this one